# Java - ServerSocket IP Address

Tags: java, networking, serversocket

After I opened a server socket, I would like to access its IP address (the one others can use to connect to). When I call

```
ServerSocket seso = new ServerSocket(port);
System.out.println(seso.getInetAddress());
```

it displays (0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0), which is only the net mask. What I would like to get is the ip the socket was actually bound to, e.g. 130.75.22.12 (or something similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freeze

It seems you are searching for water in a desert :).

You can't get the ip address of the `ServerSocket` which listens to all interfaces in the computer or from any ip address.(Before a device or program connects to the `ServerSocket`).So for querying all the networking interface's ip address jz follow the link to make a study and use those ip addresses to acheive what you need..

[Oracle Java Documentation - Querying Network Interface Addresses.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)

It seems it would be helpful for everyone.

Comment: Thanks ... I had hoped it would be possible to iterate directly over the IP adresses the ServerSocket actually listens to. So I have to combine the info from the the list of Network Interface Adresses showing all possible adresses of the computer hosting the ServerSocket together with seso.getInetAddress()?

Answer (score 1):

The `ServerSocket` is bound to an interface. You can get this interface with the `socket.getInetAddress()` which shows `0.0.0.0`. That means your server is listening on ALL interfaces you have available, so you (often) can't get a single IP address your server is listening on as you may have more than one.

More information on how to get your network interfaces:

[`NetworkInterface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html)

[`Usage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html)

Comment: I understood that a computer (or server program) can be/listen to several IP's at once (e.g. LAN, wireles, ...). Still I would like to find out *which*. I may be blind but how can I iterate over the IP adresses the ServerSocket is listening to?

Answer (score 0):

Use Socket sock= seso.accept(); it will listen for socket on the port you have given. After getting connection you can get sock.getInetAddress() to get ip and port

Comment: it will return when you connect it through client socket using another program e.g in another class you did coding as , Socket sock=new Socket(ipaddressofmachinewhereserverisrunning,portofserver);

Comment: Yes but that is not what I wanted to know ... Id like to find out the IP(s) of the ServerSocket, directly after creating it from within in the same application, e.g. for logging, window title, sending it to a meta server or other purpose. Appears to be more complex then I thought.

Answer (score 0):

For local Address you can use,

```
System.out.println(Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
```

For Server Address you use,

```
System.out.println(serversocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
```

Comment: Yes, for that you can use localAdress.

Comment: The result of is seso.getLocalSocketAddress().toString() "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:22" ... so again only the interface mask. What I am looking for is the real exisiting ip(s) of the already created ServerSocket.